# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Script'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

In my Asp.Net Core project i am trying to generate a SQL script for my database migrations using **Entity Framework 1.0 migration** but every time when i enter the update-database command i get an error as mentioned below. I am wondering why i am getting this error as i could not found this error on web.

**`A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Script'.`**

I am trying it with the following command in package manager console.

```
Update-Database -script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: AddPost
```

Instant help will be appreciable.

Comment: Believe you are meaning EF Core. If it is, please check the above link suggested by @hardkoded.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! The suggested post helped me.